# How can I add In-app screen mirroring option

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk, android-cast-api

I want to add an in-app screen mirroring option that would cast only the app's surface view/ layout/screen to cast-enable TV(Android TV). I tried different approaches but couldn't find any possible solutions.
People who have asked the same questions on SO were suggested of Remote display API which is deprecated

Here are my findings

1. Initially, I played with the Google Home app that provides a complete screen mirroring option but looks like those APIs are private and not open for us developers.
2. The Google cast SDK provides only media casting [Audio/Video], which is unsuitable for my use case. As per the documentation, I would need to create a receiver app to support media sharing between sender and TV.
3. Leon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46180689/2070800) says that cast remote display API can be used but it is [deprecated by Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastRemoteDisplay)
4. Tried this fantastic [sample app](https://github.com/ankyl/castscreen) which used to work earlier but now has stopped working

Can anyone guide me on how can I get it done?

References

- [Screen mirrorring using chrome cast example code or tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499247/screen-mirrorring-using-chrome-cast-example-code-or-tutorial)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41499834/2070800
- https://github.com/ankyl/castscreen
- https://github.com/ChannVincent/android_library_screen_mirroring_chromecast